# Difficulty telling live wire and neutral wire apart - building extension cord

Tags: power-supply, wire

I would like to build an extension cord, and have bought: 1) the plug; 2) the power strip; 3) the cable. I am running into a problem: the power strip clearly states that when connecting the cable to the strip, the live wire (brown) should be connected to one side and the neutral wire (blue) to the other side. However, my cable has not assigned colours to the wires, they are both copper coloured, so no blue or brown. Can I simply proceed without knowing which is which, or would that be dangerous?

[image: Cable, plug, and power strip]

Comment: You've bought the wrong cable. Why are you trying to build something that you can buy completed?

Comment: Neither the power strip nor the plug are polarized, so it does not matter how live and neutral are connected. Your 0.75mm2 cord is too thin for anything but very light loads (note that the power strip mentions 1.0 mm2 as a minimum and might not even be suitable for 0.75 mm2). BTW, I know from experience this "HandsOn" stuff is of very low quality. Just buy a read made one.

Comment: You seem to be doing something that is possibly dangerous and illegal. Some countries have laws that you are allowed to repair and build an extension cord if you know what you are doing. Making a new ungrounded extension cord may not be wise, if even legal. The second thing is, your selection of mains cable looks dubious. The wire is quite thin and you or someone else can easily overload it and exceed the ratings and the wire can melt and burn. Here, you can't even buy extension cords that are below 1.25 mm squared, for safety reasons. And you have unpolarized plugs, L/N are swappable.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your thoughtful and useful feedback. The reason the cable is thin (2 x 0,75mm) is that it - ideally - needs to fit in a tight space next to a shelf. I am aware that it is a thin cable that cannot handle much current. I will only plug two Sonos loudspeakers in that use at most 60W each AFAIK, and are certified for 1 amp , 240 V. According to my calculations that should be ok with this cable, but please let me know if I'm wrong! Thanks for helping me out, this is my first DIY project.

Comment: @justme I'm not disagreeing for a second with your comments about safety, but I'm just curious where "here" is.  And what jurisdictions homemade extensions would be illegal.

Comment: @jonathanjo Somewhere in Europe. For example building extension cords is specifically listed as allowed, but that's approximately most complex thing you are allowed to do here. The point is to check if it is allowed or not. And anyway, maker is responsible for the safety of it, and if it kills someone or burns house down because it is unsafe, it can affect the insurance terms. So it is just much safer, legally, to just buy an extension cord. And extension cords are not supposed to be permanently used, they should be temporary. Different legislations define how much is the limit for permanent.

Comment: So you're going to run an overly thin cable behind a bunch of books or other flammable stuff, in a space where it's hard to get at.  Uh -- sure.  Now that you have my critique of your approach -- make sure that the cord insulation is rated for at least 300V.  Better yet, check your local regulations and go by what they say (it may be 600V or something).  Usually zip cord with conductors that small is intended as speaker cord, to carry audio -- _not_ something that's designed to carry 220VAC, especially after it's been in use for years.

Answer (score 2):

Return that stuff you bought. Look instead for a flat-style 3-conductor cable that includes ground. The cables should be at least #16 AWG (1.291mm diameter, 1.31 mm^2), which can handle up to 13A.

Why? Even though your equipment is low current, there is a possibility of a short within that equipment. The cord needs to be able to handle that without melting. In addition, someone else may choose to plug in a high-current device (like a space heater, hair dryer, vacuum cleaner, etc.) into your homemade outlet, which would fry that thin 0.75mm wire in short order.

I didn't mention fusing the cord as this isn't the norm in my locale (North America), but you can consider it as well (tip o' the hat to @TimWescott and @Matt S. for suggesting this.) My opinion / bias is it's more cost-effective and less troublesome to size the wire such that a short will not fry it, and instead trip the upstream breaker.

Note: The outlet strip you show in the photo has ratings for wire sizes 1.0mm^2 and 1.5mm^2. **So in no event use a wire smaller than 1.0mm^2.** If you choose a decorative cord like you've shown, these typically have a small ridge on one side to indicate which conductor is which.

That said, it’s likely you could find a pre-made thin, discreet solution, for example, bringing power to a wall-mount TV or to an under-cabinet light. Possible IKEA item, or the Dutch equivalent of Monoprice?

Comment: Or, if you *must* use a 20awg cable, buy a fuse holder (or a plug with an integral fuse holder) and fuse the cable at no more than 1.5A.

Comment: "Why? Even though your equipment is low current, there is a possibility of..." not to mention the possibility that _someone else_ may plug a hair dryer into that thing.  The suggestion to fuse it appropriately is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use that under-sized cable, look carefully at it.  There may be a stripe down one side, or printed markings on it that distinguish the top from the bottom.  Then pick one side as live, and the other as neutral.

The electrons don't really care what colour the wire is.  It's up to ypu to make sure you wire it consistently.

Comment: It also does not matter a bit how it is wired, because both the sockets and plugs are non-polar, so you can anyway not be sure which wire will be live or neutral, because it depends which way you insert the plug into wall socket.